# Can I use a CAST inside a LINQ to Entities query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-sql

I have a LINQ to Entities query

```
From item In ctx.Items
Select new {
    ListPrice = item.Cost / (1M - item.Markup)
};
```

Can I specify to EF that I want it to apply a `cast` to the list price before querying and materializing it<sup>1</sup>?  Is there something like `EntityFunctions.Cast` maybe?  Or can I use the ESQL `cast` function?

I want the LINQ to generate a SQL query along these lines

```
SELECT cast((Cost / (1 - Markup)) as decimal(10, 2)) AS ListPrice
```

<sup>1</sup>My goal is to get rid of a bunch of precision/scale the query.  Because there's decimal subtraction and division, the result of the math is a decimal(38, 26)!  That's way more than .NET can handle and more than I need.

Comment: Can't you use a `Convert` members?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh `Convert.ToDecimal` is not recognized by EF

Comment: the only functions I know are from [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your cast is not present in these functions.

Comment: Did you try  EntityFunctions ? For example `EntityFunctions.Truncate(item.Cost / (1M - item.Markup), 2)` : see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus `Truncate` does not change the scale / precision of the returned value.  (It actually translates it to a SQL Server Round).

Comment: You're right. The other ways would be to work with computed columns (but.. seems that you're working with esql, not sql server), or make a view and try to query from the view.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I'm working w/ SQL Server.  I only suggested ESQL b/c it has the `cast` operator I need.  I know I could use a computed column or a view.  I'd like to do it in code if possible.

Comment: Well, there's also a cast operator in sql server, that's why I got confused. Anyway, the computed column will probably be the only / better solution in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF allows you to map CLR functions to database functions using the [`DbFunction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctionattribute(v=vs.113).aspx) attribute.  Unfortunately, it looks like the built in `cast` and `convert` are not functions and it does not look like you can map to them.

Instead you can create a UDF which does the cast and map it in the `DbModel`.  The mapping API is complicated so I would use the [Code First Functions](https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/) library to do it for you.  (If your using Database first or Model first, you can do the mapping manually in your SSDL and CSDL<sup>1</sup>).  Also, there's no way to do dynamic casting inside a UDF so you'll need to pick write separate functions for each cast you want.  Here's an example for a `cast(field as decimal(10,4)`.

```sql
-- In SQL Server
CREATE FUNCTION ClrRound_10_4
(
    @value decimal(28, 10)
)
RETURNS decimal(10,4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @converted decimal(10,4)

    SELECT @converted = cast(round(@value, 4) as decimal(10,4))

    RETURN @converted

END
GO
```

```
//In your DbContext class
using CodeFirstStoreFunctions;

public class MyContext : DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder) {
        builder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention("dbo", typeof(Udf));
    }

    //etc
}

//In a static class named Udf (in the same namespace as your context)
using System.Data.Entity;

public static class Udf {
    [DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "ClrRound_10_4")]
    public static decimal ClrRound_10_4(decimal value) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot call UDF directly!");
    }
}

//In your LINQ query
from item in ctx.Items
select new {
    ListPrice = Udf.ClrRound_10_4(item.Cost / (1M - item.Markup))
};
```

<sup>1</sup> See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/01/07/model-defined-functions.aspx) or this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456857(v=vs.100).aspx) article for more details.