# Perform convert(NVARCHAR, ValidDate.Date, 102) with Linq to entities

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities

I have an SQL statement:

```
Select convert(NVARCHAR, MyDate, 102) + ' ' + convert(NVARCHAR, AccountId) AS Temp from MyTable
```

I want to convert it with Linq to Entities. I was suggested to query MyDate and AccountId and with Linq to object I can use .ToString(). But I want the sql server to make the conversion by performing the convert() method.

I was happy to find [SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.8) class which helps to perform methods on the server side. Unfortunately, there is no `Convert()` method there only `StringConvert()` which can only convert a double to string. Can I perform `convert(NVARCHAR, MyDate, 102)` on the server?

Comment: Maybe import it as a function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/stored-procedures/query

Comment: @Charlieface You are right I can write a stored procedure and import it. Or easier I can send the raw sql statement to the server, but in that case I did not use too much Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34072720/5852947) that you can not use Cast and Convert in Linq to entities which is sad. The referenced page suggested to use User defined functions but UDF has performance impact.

I realized though I can not convert a `date` to `string`, I can convert a `date` to date part (`int`), that to `double`, and that to `string`.

```
Temp = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", MyDate), 4) + "."
            + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("month", MyDate), 2) + "."
            + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("day", MyDate), 2) + ". - "
            + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.AccountId, 5)
```

This is not the nicest solution because I can use "01" instead of " 1".